# Ubuntu 20.04 intermittent system freezes

Tags: 20.04, freeze, crash, amd-processor

I have periodic freezes on my linux desktop for quite a long time, starting from when I was on Debian 10. When I use Windows, I don't have any of these. During the freezes, the system just doesn't respond to any interactions. The only way is to reboot the system.
My build:

- **CPU**: AMD Ryzen 5 1600
- **GPU**: Nvidia GeForce GT 1030
- **RAM**: 2x RAM A-DATA 8GB 2400 MHz
- **Motherboard**: PRIME A320M-K Bios ver. 4023
- **OS**: Ubuntu 20.04.1

There is not so much info in `/var/log/syslog` before a freeze:

```
systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Succeeded.
systemd[3842]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
systemd-resolved[660]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
systemd-resolved[660]: message repeated 3 times: [ Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.]
systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service: Succeeded.
systemd[1]: Finished Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
```

If I need to post some other info, please let me know.

Comment: System doesn't respond, moving cursor etc. You aren't specific, is this a desktop or server? (by cursor do you mean mouse pointer? or just cursor?) Can you still `ssh` into the machine?  Do SysRq commands direct via keyboard cause reactions? (ie. bypassing any locked GUI)

Comment: @guiverc hey, thanks I've corrected the question. This is a desktop machine, nothing works after the system freeze

Comment: Nothing works, so you can't direct the kernel to reboot via sysrq, nor tell it to turn off (ie. SysRq+REISUB or like commands) ... if these aren't responding it means you have a kernel crash

Comment: @guiverc hmm I think in case of kernel crash i'd have something in /var/log/syslog right?

Comment: Nope; if kernel has crashed there will be nothing in any logs as nothing remains to write logs (no file-system is accessible)...  SysRq bypasses GUI/desktop, or any form of shell or user environment programs and speaks to kernel directly which is useful as it gives a clue as to OS itself still reacting/running even if all user-functions (gui, terminals etc) are dead.